# remove duplication from list on field using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am new in C# and Linq I am facing one problem to remove duplicate records I need to Remove duplicate records those who don't have `Dept`. Below is a quick example using an employee list

```
 private static void Main()
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "John", Age=23, Dept='computer'});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 2, Name = "Mary", Age=25, Dept='computer'});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 3, Name = "Amber",Age=23, Dept=''});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 4, Name = "Kathy",Age=25, Dept=''});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 5, Name = "Lena", Age=27, Dept='computer'});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 6, Name = "John", Age=28, Dept=''});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 7, Name = "Kathy",Age=27, Dept='Tester'});
 empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 8, Name = "John", Age=23, Dept='computer'});
        var dup = empList
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.FName })
            .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);

        foreach (var x in dup)
        {
            Response.Write(x.Count + " " + x.Name);
        }
    }
    class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public char Dept { get; set; }
    }
```

final output look  like this
output example:-

```
    empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, Name = "John", Age=23, Dept='computer'});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 2, Name = "Mary", Age=25, Dept='computer'});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 3, Name = "Amber",Age=23, Dept=''}); 
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 5, Name = "Lena", Age=27, Dept='computer'});
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 7, Name = "Kathy",Age=27, Dept='Tester'});
 empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 8, Name = "John", Age=23, Dept='computer'});
```

I need to remove those duplicate record those who dont have dept.

condition 1
duplicate records will come multiple times but one single record which don't have dept that should have to delete. and remaining record will display on output

Comment: So if there are duplicates and both have a `Dept` then you'd keep both?

Comment: So you're considering a duplicate just as having the same name?

Comment: And what about non-duplicated employee without dept?

Comment: And what if two employees have same name, but different age?

Comment: @oopaewem Which one?  Just take the first one with a `Dept`?  What if you have dupes and none of them have a `Dept`?

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly comprises a duplicate? Matching name and Age? ID? All of the fields?

Comment: But what if there are multiple people with the same name and both have a Department? What if neither?

Comment: can you filter before your groupby? you can do something like empList.Where(x => x.Depth != ' ' || x.Depth == null )

Comment: Also just curious, but why are you incorrectly using single quotes around the `Dept` strings?  Also is it `Name` or `FName`?

Comment: It is obvious by the many comments, that your question needs clarification. Please update your original posting with all the relevant details. Do not rely on the comments section to add critical information.

Comment: @oopaewem Here's the problem.  There are at least two interruptations of what you want.  Both work with your given example, but it's not clear which one is correct.  Do you remove records because they have the same name as another record, but no Dept, or do you remove all the records that do not have a Dept except for the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ID is unique you could use this approach (`Dept` seems to be a string):

```
var empDupNoDepartment = empList
    .GroupBy(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Dept) ? int.MinValue : x.ID)
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .ToList();
```

This keeps only the first employee with empty `Dept`.

Comment: I think the OP only wants to remove empty `Dept` records if there is a record with the same name that does have a `Dept`.

Comment: @juharr: but the expected output suggests something different. Amber is kept but there is no other employee Amber. It's simply the first with empty `Dept`. My understanding is: remove all empty Dept duplicates, keep only the first. All other employees remain

Comment: I took it to mean that record 4 and 6 are removed because there are records with the same name and a `Dept` while it keeps record 3 because there isn't another record with that name.  It just happens that your approach will give the same results for the example input/output, but doesn't seem to match up with what the OP says.

Comment: @juharr: OP has said: _"I need to remove those duplicate records, those who dont have dept.... and remaining record will display on output"_

Comment: And my interruption of that is a duplicate is a record with the same name and when you have duplicates remove the one that does not have a `Dept`.  But really this question isn't completely clear.

Comment: @juharr: well, OP hasnt mentioned the Name to identify duplicates but i see where you're coming from. He has used a query which groups by this property. Really not clear

Comment: Based on the latest update it looks like you had a better understanding than I did.

Answer (score 0):

```
from e in empList
group e by e.Name into g
select g.FirstOrDefault(e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Dept)) ?? g.First();
```

Just group by Name and select either first employee with Dept or just first employee.

Output:

```
[
  { "ID": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 23, "Dept": "computer" },
  { "ID": 2, "Name": "Mary", "Age": 25, "Dept": "computer" },
  { "ID": 3, "Name": "Amber", "Age": 23,"Dept": "" },
  { "ID": 7, "Name": "Kathy", "Age": 27, "Dept": "Tester" },
  { "ID": 5, "Name": "Lena", "Age": 27, "Dept": "computer" }
]
```

---

If you want to keep all entries with non-empty Dept, then

```
Func<Employee, bool> hasDept = e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Dept);
var result = empList
       .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
       .SelectMany(g => g.Any(hasDept) ? g.Where(hasDept) : g.Take(1));
```

Query syntax:

```
from e in empList
group e by e.Name into g
from e in g.Any(hasDept) ? g.Where(hasDept) : g.Take(1)
select e;
```

Output:

```
[
  { "ID": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 23, "Dept": "computer" },
  { "ID": 8, "Name": "John", "Age": 23, "Dept": "computer" },  <== difference
  { "ID": 2, "Name": "Mary", "Age": 25, "Dept": "computer" },
  { "ID": 3, "Name": "Amber", "Age": 23,"Dept": "" },
  { "ID": 7, "Name": "Kathy", "Age": 27, "Dept": "Tester" },
  { "ID": 5, "Name": "Lena", "Age": 27, "Dept": "computer" }
]
```

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what the OP wants, but the latest update has 3 records with the name John and it only removes the one with the empty `Dept`.

Comment: @juharr yep, I still don't get what OP wants. It's not clear what to do if all records with some name don't have Dept

Answer (score 0):

Create this class:

```
class Dept
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the query:

```
var dup = empList
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name })

    // Employees with duplicate name
    .Select(group => new { Emps = group.Select(x => x)})

    // From duplicates select only those that have a department 
    .SelectMany(x => {
        var emps = x.Emps.Where(y => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y.Dept));
        var employeesWithDept = emps.GroupBy(g => g.Name );


        IEnumerable<Dept> a = 
        employeesWithDept.Select(g => new Dept { Employees = g.ToList(), Name = g.Key.ToString(), Count = g.Count()});
        return a;
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have here is an example of why someone's name is a terrible primary key for anything ever.

All Values:

```
var hasDept = empList.Where(x=>x.Dept != null && x.Dept.Trim() != string.Empty).ToList();
```

Distinct Values:

```
var hasDept =  empList.Where(x=>x.Dept != null && x.Dept.Trim() != string.Empty).Distinct().ToList();
```

Those will get you the ones that have a department.  If you also want to get the ones that don't have one, but don't have a duplicate entry which does have a department, the easiest way is probably:

```
var noDept = empList.Where(x=>x.Dept == null || x.Dept.Trim() == string.Empty).Distinct().ToList()  //gets all the ones with no dept

var all = noDept;
foreach(var e in all)
{
        if(hasDept.Where(x.Name == e.Name).Count == 0)
           all.Add(e);
}
```

Comment: `Distinct` when used on a collection of a class that does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` will end up comparing on reference equality and in the example not actually remove anything.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about it, but if you just want to remove empty Dept employee with a Linq you should be able to do :

```
empList = empList.Where(Dept => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Dept)).Distinct().ToList()
```

Best regards !

Comment: Distinct will use reference equality if the type does not implement IEquatable

Comment: If you are not sure, then ask clarification from original poster before guessing at what the answer might be.

Comment: i am asto doing same thing  but i dont have to use distinct